Shell extension manager errors on Ubuntu 24.04
I have got a lot of errors in there just posting 2 of them atm
2024-04-27T09:00:03.860270+02:00 Desktop gnome-shell[1659]: Extension ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com: Error: No signal connection 10 found#012#012Stack trace:#012  _disconnect@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/core/_signals.js:58:15#012  disable@file:///usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com/extension.js:33:35#012  _callExtensionDisable@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/extensionSystem.js:211:49#012  _onEnabledExtensionsChanged@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/extensionSystem.js:644:24#012  _loadExtensions/<@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/extensionSystem.js:736:18#012  createCheckedMethod/<@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/core/overrides/Gio.js:730:46#012  disableExtension@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/extensionSystem.js:305:29#012  DisableExtension@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/shellDBus.js:457:38#012  _handleMethodCall@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/core/overrides/Gio.js:329:38#012  _wrapJSObject/<@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/core/overrides/Gio.js:408:34#012  @resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/init.js:21:20#012  
2024-04-27T09:00:03.993348+02:00 Desktop gnome-shell[1659]: Extension dash-to-panel@jderose9.github.com: Error: No signal connection 10 found#012#012Stack trace:#012  _disconnect@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/core/_signals.js:58:15#012  disable@file:///usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com/extension.js:33:35#012  _enable@file:///home/amir/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/dash-to-panel@jderose9.github.com/extension.js:112:29#012  enable@file:///home/amir/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/dash-to-panel@jderose9.github.com/extension.js:71:16#012  _callExtensionDisable@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/extensionSystem.js:230:55#012  async*_onEnabledExtensionsChanged@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/extensionSystem.js:644:24#012  _loadExtensions/<@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/extensionSystem.js:736:18#012  createCheckedMethod/<@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/core/overrides/Gio.js:730:46#012  disableExtension@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/extensionSystem.js:305:29#012  DisableExtension@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/shellDBus.js:457:38#012  _handleMethodCall@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/core/overrides/Gio.js:329:38#012  _wrapJSObject/<@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/core/overrides/Gio.js:408:34#012  @resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/init.js:21:20#012

I have also quite a few warning for gnome shell if it is related, can I get help to track down the problem?

the risks of updating to a new release before the devs have had a chance to update their apps to a newer version of GNOME. The only way is to approach the devs directly reporting issues in the hope that will spur them on to upgrading their code.

@graham, if you look at the first one closely  Extension ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com, and it has the same problem as the second one.

Actually graham was right (though cryptic :)), unfortunately dash to panel is not working for 24.04 (yet), just removed it and it seems everything works ok for now.
